# Apple Watch not unlocking Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-watch, unlock

I have an Apple Watch Series 3 and MacBook Pro 2017.  I tried pairing my Apple Watch to my MacBook and it worked, but I can't use it for login.  I can only use my Apple Watch to authenticate within apps (ie. in the security tab of system preferences, I can click the lock icon and unlock it with my Apple Watch).  I can't use my Apple Watch to unlock the MacBook.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What version of macOS is running on your MBP, and which version of WatchOS is running on your Apple Watch 3? The MBP needs to be running [High Sierra or later](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204689#autounlock).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put that.  I'm running Big Sur on my MBP and watchOS 7.3.

Comment: [This document](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT206995) at Apple Support states: "Your Mac and Apple Watch are signed in to iCloud with the same Apple ID, and your Apple ID is using two-factor authentication." Perhaps you have not enabled 2FA for you Apple ID?

Comment: Yeah I do.  Good thought though.  The weird thing is that it works within apps.

Comment: Have you restarted your Apple Watch?

Comment: Yeah I tried that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122999/discussion-between-icondaemon-and-salocor).

Comment: I figured it out!!!  So I unpaired and repaired my watch, but that didn't fix it.  While I was doing this, I noticed I had an update on my watch.  After the update, everything is working great!  Thank you for the help!  Not sure I would have ever noticed there was an update without you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I thought I figured it out, but it stopped working shortly after.  So after much troubleshooting, I really did figure it out.  Wifi has to be enabled on the Apple Watch for the unlock to work.

It's funny that none of the apple support documents say that.  I just use bluetooth on my watch, so I tend to keep Wifi off.  When I reset my watch, Wifi was automatically turned back on, which would explain why it worked for a while.